# Zero pad file names using find and execdir flag

Tags: bash, awk, find

I'm using smplayer and it doesn't sort files by natural order, e.g after playing `1*.sth` it will jump to `11*.sth` instead of `2*.sth`. but as I've checked if I change file names to zero pad them then this player will sort files in the correct order.(by `*` I mean any character such as dash, space, dot, etc.)
now I'm trying to write a one line and if possible one time executable code that will check and zero-pad all video and srt files.
I have this code to find all files I need to rename:

~~ `find . -type f -regex "[^0].*\.\(mp4\|srt\)"` ~~
~~ `find . -type f -name '[1-9]*.mp4' -o -name '[1-9]*.srt'` ~~

```bash
find . '(' -name '[1-9]*.mp4' -o -name '[1-9]*.srt' ')' -type f
```

I know that `find` has a `execdir` flag which will execute a command and the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file.
this information is helpful because if I want to run the result command from a very top node of my directory tree so I don't need to be worry about where is the file located.
now the problem is I don't know how to use bash script to zero-pad a file name and use this function as a command for `-execdir` flag of `find` method.

this code will

```bash
awk '{ split($0, arr, "/"); print arr[2] }'
```

I have a python script which is working for me, but I'm looking to find a one-line bash script to do the job.

```py
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

cmd = r'find ./ -type f -regex "[^0].*\.\(mp4\|srt\)"'
exc = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

pathes = list(map(bytes.decode, exc.splitlines()))
files = list(map(Path, pathes))

for file in files:
    if file.name[0].isdigit() and file.name[0] != "0":
        num = ""
        for char in file.name:
            if not char.isdigit():
                break
            num += char
        file.rename(file.with_name(file.name.replace(num, num.rjust(3, "0"))))
```

[image]

Comment: `11.sth` coming between `1.sth` and `2.sth` is a natural order - it's just an alphabetic string comparison order instead of numeric. Are you sure you need to rename your files instead of just running `sort -n` on the list? If so, [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. In particular show how many digits should be present before the `.` in each file name.

Comment: well, if you're watching a series usually you don't like it if your player jumps form `1.mp4` to  `11.mp4` instead of `2.mp4`; that is my problem sir.
there is no information about actual file names only thing I know is the name will start with some digits but after the digits there could be any character (space, dot, comma, dash, ...)
for example if file name is `1- Welcome.mp4` I need to change that to `001- Welcome.mp4` normally there aren't more than 100 files in a series but does the number of zeros matter? idc.

Comment: `find . -type f -name '[1-9]*.mp4' -o -name '[1-9]*.srt'` is like `find . '(' -type f -a -name '[1-9]*.mp4' ')' -o -name '[1-9]*.srt'`. That  is it finds *regular* `.mp4` files or `.srt` files of any type (regular (`f`) or directory or symlink/sockets/fifos...)

Comment: Changing `1- Welcome.mp4` to `001- Welcome.mp4` is not the same problem as changing `1.sth` to `001.sth`. When posting a question, make sure your sample input/output are truly representative of your real data.

Comment: My first point was you don't need to rename your files to have 2 come before 11, you can just sort them numerically instead of alphabetically - that's a choice you make when iterating through any list.

Answer (score 2):

To zero-pad to length 4 for instance the number at the start of all `mp4` and `srt` file, with `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(**/)(<->)(*.(mp4|srt))(#q.)' '$1${(l[4][0])2}$3'
```

Or if you have the `rename` command from `perl`'s `File::Rename`:

```
find . '(' -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.srt' ')' -type f -print0 |
  rename -0d 's/^\d+/sprintf "%04d", $&/e'
```

Note that `-regex`, in the `find` implementations that support it matches against the whole path not just the name of the files and is anchored by default.

In

> ```
> find . -type f -regex "[^0].*\.\(mp4\|srt\)"
> ```

All the paths will start with `./`. Could be for instance `./dir/01.mp4` which matches that regexp because it starts with a character other than `0` (`.`) followed by 0 or more characters followed by `.mp4`.

You likely meant something like:

```
find . '(' -name '[123456789]*.mp4' -o -name '[123456789]*.srt' ')' -type f
```

To find regular files whose *name* starts with a digit other than 0.

Or:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/[0123456789]{1,3}([^0123456789/][^/]*)?\.(mp4|srt)' -type f
```

For regular files whose name starts with a sequence of digits whose length is less than 4.

If your `find` is GNU `find`, replace `-E .` with `. -regextype posix-extended`. `-E` is the equivalent for the `find` implementations found on BSDs.

Comment: yeah, excuse me

Comment: thank you for advice, it seems this one is better `find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|srt\)" -name '[^0]*'`

Comment: `-name '[^0]*'` or its standard equivalent `-name '[!0]*'` (`-regex` in any case is not standard) would match on file names that don't start with a digit such as `foo.mp4`